# What is the difference between SMS Gateway and Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs, sms-gateway

I am currently using SMS Gateway to send bulk SMS. Can I use Amazon SQS Instead of SMS Gateway ?. What is the difference between the use of SMS Gateway and SQS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same at all, SQS doesn't send SMS, it's a queue between your apps. It's a message broker (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker) like RabitMQ, ActiveMQ, Kafka,...

Those services allow you to send requests and messages to your applications asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Just because the acronyms are similar, that doesn't mean they are the same thing.  [SMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS) (Short Messaging Service - e.g. Text messaging) is not the same as [SQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Simple_Queue_Service) (Simple Queue Service - Amazon message broker).  Infact, just look at the tags you have included for details!

Answer (score 0):

Amazon SQS supports programmatic sending of messages via internet service applications as a way to communicate over the Internet.  And SMS Gateway translates the message you send it and makes it friendly for delivery over the Telco network to be able to reach the recipient.